# Person trapped in a maze with connected and disconnected walls

Tags: mazes

A person is trapped in the center of a labyrinth, which has an exit and walls
disconnected. Before going into despair she thinks of a way to find the
output. For this she decides to keep her left hand in contact with a wall and
always walk in one direction. Is she guaranteed to find the way out? Now imagine that the walls are disconnected. Is she guaranteed to find the way out?

I believe that if the walls are connected, there is always the possibility that it will be walking in circles if, for example, the labyrinth is circular. But what about the case where the walls are disconnected?

([Source](https://www.estantevirtual.com.br/sebocaprichoi/andre-s-tavares-da-silva-org--sudoku-puzzles-100-volume-6-100-jogos-de-raciocinio-logica-e-concentracao--2643425496?show_suggestion=0))

Comment: You have been told [recently](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106204/non-numeric-password-puzzle#comment300157_106204)  that if you're posting puzzles found somewhere else, then the source should be given. Could you please [edit] your source in, and start posting these puzzles with a source given originally?

Comment: I received it from a friend via telegram. But ok ... I will try to get the source with him and pay attention to this when I ask again. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the walls are connected,

> it always works. Imagine you paint the walls on your left as you walk past them. If you reach the same place again, that means you've painted all the way around a connected segment of walls. Since *all* the walls are connected, you must have painted the outside of the maze, and so you must have escaped.

If the walls are not connected,

> you can easily be stuck forever. For instance, if you start in the middle of this maze, you'll never get out to the outside layer.
>  [image]

Comment: So when she gets to the exit of the innermost circle, will she leave and walk around it until she reaches the (now) entrance to him again?

Comment: @gmn_1450 Yes, that's what the strategy says to do.

Comment: There is still the case where she is surrounded by the walls.  I.e. there is no path to the exit.